# Get a List of all Unique Values from Custom Text Field using REST Api or PNPJS

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, caml-query, pnpjs

Hi i am stuck in a task i need to improve a SPFX WebPart.

I need to create a autocomplete field that has a list of all possible values all-ready filled in in a Custom text field.

The reason is we need to do a filter by this field value for a search.

I was doing this like this before

```
var fieldValues: Set<string> = new Set();
this._sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").fields.getByTitle("Field Title")().then(value => {
      const staticName = value.StaticName;
    
      const itemList = this._sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.select(staticName).filter(staticName + " ne null").orderBy(staticName).top(1000)();
      itemList.then(values => {
        values.forEach(value => {
          this.fieldValues.add(value[staticName]);
        });
      });
    });
```

This was working fine, till it came that the List Grew too much, and now i am getting a limit error and i a missing some values that do not come in the top 1000.

Any one can give me hand o how i could handle this?

I read i could do this with a CAML query and tried this

```
  const camlQuery =
    '<Query>' +
    '<Where>' +
    '<IsNotNull>' +
    '<FieldRef name="' + staticName + '"></FieldRef>' +
    '</IsNotNull>' +
    '</Where>' +
    '<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE">' +
    '<FieldRef name="' + staticName + '"></FieldRef>' +
     '</GroupBy>' +
    '</Query>' +
    '<ViewFields>' +
     '<FieldRef Name="' + staticName + '" />' +
     '</ViewFields>'
    '';

  const qr = this._sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").getItemsByCAMLQuery({ ViewXml: camlQuery });
  qr.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

But i could not get it to group or filter.

I have a SPFX Webpart with react.
Any one can give me a hand here?

Comment: You can get up to 5000 items using `top`. Try using 5000 instead of 1000. Let me know if it resolves your issue.